# A python way to adjusting sizes of cells in heatmaps like this

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn, heatmap

Is anyone familiar with a python package or way to plot heatmaps like this? 
I have utilization rates in time by space typologies and would like to plot occupancy rates like this.

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: [This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/better-heatmaps-and-correlation-matrix-plots-in-python-41445d0f2bec) looks interesting for your visualization.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps [use `ggplot2` within Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-ggplot2-in-python-74ab8adec129) with the `plotnine` package, along with the `geom_point()` function.

Here's code in R to demonstrate how it works. The routines should be identical in Python (albeit with the above changes in grammar, from R to Python):

```
> library(ggplot2)
> p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=cyl, size=cyl))
> p <- p + geom_point(shape=15, fill=NA)
> print(p)
```

Here, the `mtcars` data frame (built into R) has the usual `x` and `y` parameters. The `color` of a point is specified by the continuous range of values in the `cyl` column. The `size` of a point (radius, in the case of circular point, but diagonal in the case of a square) is specified also by the categorical values in `cyl`.

[image: Demonstration of geom_point()]

In `plotnine`, the code might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from plotnine import *
from plotnine.data import mtcars

p = (ggplot(mtcars, aes(x='wt', y='mpg', color='cyl', size='cyl')) +
        geom_point(shape='s', fill=None))

p.save("../results/test.png")
```

This gives the following result:

[image: matplotlib/plotnine demo figure]

Season to taste: Instead of using the `mtcars` data frame, you'd use a data frame you pull in via `pandas`, along with adjusting the requisite columns to specify position, coloring, and sizing of point elements.